# Swift 3 and backendless - how do i upload an image?

Tags: ios, swift, image, upload, backendless

I'm building an APP with Swift 3 and backendless and i'm having trouble to upload an image from my APP (the user will take a pic from camera or from photoLibrary) to backendless.
The APP is saving the images to the photoLibrary :

```
func savePic() {
    let imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(itemPic.image!, 0.5);
    let compressedJPEGImage = UIImage(data: imageData!);
    UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(compressedJPEGImage!, nil, nil, nil);

}
```

What is the taken image address?

And how do i upload it to backEndLess?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use [`Backendless.file.upload`](https://backendless.com/documentation/files/ios/files_file_upload.htm) method.

For example:

```
func uploadImage(_ img:UIImage){
    //convert UIImage to jpg Data with 0.5 compressionQuality (use 1 for full quality)
    let jpg=UIImageJPEGRepresentation(img, 0.5);
    //saving file name with current timestamp
    let fileName="IMG_\(Date().timeIntervalSince1970).jpg";
    //uploading image asynchronously 
    Backendless.sharedInstance().file.upload("imagesFolder/\(fileName)", content:jpg, response: {(res) in
        //uploading image finished
    }, error: {(e) in
        //failed to upload
        print("error code: \(e!.faultCode)");
    })
}
```

If you need to upload it in `PNG` format use [`UIImagePNGRepresentation`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/1624096-uiimagepngrepresentation)  instead of [`IImageJPEGRepresentation`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/1624115-uiimagejpegrepresentation)

To upload an Image directly picked by user from saved photos album or taken by camera you can do it like this:

1. Use `UINavigationControllerDelegate` & `UIImagePickerControllerDelegate`
2. Specify [`UIImagePickerControllerSourceType`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiimagepickercontrollersourcetype) to be used, such as: `.photoLibrary`, `.camera` or `.savedPhotosAlbum`
3. Upload the created UIImage when user [`didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiimagepickercontrollerdelegate/1619126-imagepickercontroller)

Here an example:

```
class MyViewController : UIViewController, UINavigationControllerDelegate, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate{

var imgPicker = UIImagePickerController();

var backendless = Backendless.sharedInstance();

override func viewDidLoad() {
    imgPicker.delegate = self;
}

@IBAction func imgFromCamera(_ btn:UIButton){
    imgPicker.sourceType = .camera;//image picker with camera
    show(imgPicker, sender: self);//open image picker
}

@IBAction func imgFromSavedPhotos(_ btn:UIButton){
    imgPicker.sourceType = .savedPhotosAlbum;//image picker from saved photos
    show(imgPicker, sender: self);//open image picker
}

func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any]) {
    let img = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as! UIImage;
    uploadImage(img);
    dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil);
}

func uploadImage(_ img:UIImage){
    let jpg=UIImageJPEGRepresentation(img, 1);//full scale JPG
    //let png=UIImagePNGRepresentation(img);//full scale PNG
    let fileName="IMG_\(Date().timeIntervalSince1970).jpg";
    //upload img
    Backendless.sharedInstance().file.upload("imagesFolder/\(fileName)", content:jpg, response: {(res) in
     //successfully uploaded
    }, error: {(e) in
        //failed to upload
    })
}

func imagePickerControllerDidCancel(_ picker: UIImagePickerController) {
    dismiss(animated: false, completion: {
        print("user didn't pick any image");
    });
}
}
```

Also keep in mind that to use those you should declare: [NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CocoaKeys.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009251-SW17) & [NSCameraUsageDescription](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CocoaKeys.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009251-SW24) in you `Info.plist` otherwise it crash in `iOS 10` as stated in linked reference.

Here an example:

```
<key>NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription</key>
<string>Your explanation here</string>
<key>NSCameraUsageDescription</key>
<string>Your explanation here</string>
```